# How do I execute jquery plugin with options and methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this [plugin](https://github.com/mrmarkfrench/country-select-js#options) and based on the documentation there are Options and Public Methods. I would need to specify some options as well as using some of the public methods.

How do I go about doing this? Do I have to specify 1 by 1 like this :

```
$("#country").countrySelect({
  defaultCountry: "jp",
  onlyCountries: ['us', 'gb', 'ch', 'ca', 'do', 'jp'],
  preferredCountries: ['ca', 'gb', 'us'],
  responsiveDropdown: true
});

$("#country").countrySelect("setCountry", "United States");
```

Or I can combine them without having to put another $("#country").countrySelect(); ?

Apologize if this has been asked somewhere, I have no idea what are the keyword search for this issue. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Unless your plugin supports it, otherwise no, it's not possible to combine different functionalities

Comment: In this case, I would suggest that "defaultCountry" is the same as "setCountry" - but that's specific to your example, not in general.  Although, without looking at what it's doing, semantically the terms `selectCountry` and `setCountry` are the same - so perhaps `defaultCountry` also means something completely different (from the description "select" means "add").

Comment: Most jquery plugins also support chaining, so you might be able to do:  `$("#country").countrySelect({ ..options..}).countrySelect("setCountry", "United States");`

Comment: Thanks guys for the help! Seems like chaining is what I am looking for! =D